# Remove Duplicate Column in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to inner join two tables in a SQL database but I keep getting two of the same columns. The first encounter_id (first column) is the one I want to keep and remove the third column with the second counter_id. I am not sure why the second encounter_id has the same values as patient_nbr.

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
FROM dbo.PatientVisit p
INNER JOIN dbo.VisitSummary c ON c.encounter_id = p.patient_nbr
WHERE admission_type_id NOT LIKE '%?' 
  AND discharge_disposition_id  NOT LIKE '%?' 
  AND admission_source_id NOT LIKE '%?' 
  AND time_in_hospital NOT LIKE '%?' 
  AND payer_code NOT LIKE '%?' 
  AND medical_specialty NOT LIKE '%?' 
  AND readmitted NOT LIKE '%?'
ORDER BY p.patient_nbr;
```

Results of my code when executed:

```
encounter_id    patient_nbr encounter_id    admission_type_id   discharge_disposition_id    admission_source_id time_in_hospital    payer_code  medical_specialty
236641494   91493064    91493064    5   17  17  12  MD  Psychiatry
224775720   93318030    93318030    1   1   6   7   UN  InternalMedicine
302494340   93318030    93318030    1   1   6   7   UN  InternalMedicine
290599404   97623540    97623540    1   4   6   1   MC  InternalMedicine
101453316   98083818    98083818    2   1   1   3   HM  Surgery-Cardiovascular/Thoracic
275370966   103155624   103155624   2   1   1   5   BC  Surgery-Cardiovascular/Thoracic
278525676   103155624   103155624   2   1   1   5   BC  Surgery-Cardiovascular/Thoracic
```

Comment: List the columns that you want explicitly.

Comment: You shouldn't use *

Comment: I want to keep the all the columns except the third column

Comment: I actually tried doing "SELECT  p.patient_nbr, c.*" but the results give me the second column and third column which isn't right because they're the same values

Comment: Change `p.*, c.*` to `p.column1, p.column2, c.column3, c.column4`

Comment: Ok that works now, I guess I just have to write out the columns. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to change the query.

because there's a no way to select all column except one_column in SQL.

```
SELECT p.COLUMN_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME
```

Thanks.